trying to run nginx through cloudflare tunnel
I have setup a cloudflare tunnel on an access server on the same network as my server where my application is hosted. I have created a zero trust application and configured my cloudflare domain to forward the requests to my application through the tunnel. I have given just the ip of my application example: http://172.16.1.92.
When I try to access the server on that ip without using the domain, I am able to access all functionality of the web app. But, when I try to access it through the domain, it only loads the home page of the application and I am unable to login or sign in. It does not show any errors in the nginx logs, the access log shows the following:
172.16.1.119 - - [21/Jun/2024:12:42:17 +0000] "POST /users/sign_in HTTP/1.1" 422 0 "https://example-application.com/users/sign_in" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X XX_XX_X) AppleWebKit/XXX.XX.XX (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/XX.XX.XX Safari/XXX.X.XXXX.X.X Ddg/XX.X.X"

I am able to access my web application perfectly fine when I just visit the url http://172.16.1.92:3000 or even directly through the nginx proxy http://172.16.1.92.
this is my nginx conf on the server:
events {

}

http {
    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default upgrade;
        ''      close;
    }
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

    server {

        listen 80;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
            proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
            proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Server $host;
            proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
        }

        location /cable {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;

            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_pass_request_headers on;

            proxy_buffering off;
            proxy_redirect off;
        }
    }

}

What can I do to forward all traffic correctly when accessing through my cloudflare domain through my tunnel?
I was expecting to access my application and it’s features completely through the domain tunnel configuration I have setup on cloudflare.

having same issue. any luck on this?
